# Is repeatedly tapping the bush beneficial?

Tags: sword-and-sworcery

In Superbrothers: Sword and Sworcery (etc), there are an awful lot of bushes.  Everywhere I go, there are bushes that can be tapped.  I tip tap on them from time to time, but nothing ever seems to come of it.

Most of the other stuff in the game has some sort of interaction tied to it, even if it's just a bit of funny dialog.  Is there any benefit to tapping the bushes?  Should I repeatedly tap the bush, or is once enough?  Is there a specific bush I should be tapping?

Comment: As far as I know there is no benefit (I spent many hours doing it), but still I keep tapping them just in case :P